# Text box with a clear button inside in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a lot on my site text boxes whose content is a date
So I will not have to check correctness did it read-only
Until now next to each text box was  two buttons, one to add date opened popup calendar, second to delete the date (values ​​not required)
Now I wanted to go to ajax calendarextender that the buttons were just ugly
My problem is that this control is not have delete button, and I do want to allow the user to deleted but not cancel the properties read-only to text box And I do not want to leave the ugly button.

My question: 
If calendarextender ajax or something similar with a delete button from the popup
Alternatively if you have the option text box with a delete button inside( as text boxes IE10)

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054369/it-is-possible-to-add-none-option-in-ajax-toolkit-calendar-extender/12623676#12623676 Be warned that approach with customizing calendar extender might not working due to changes in extender's code since answer was posted

Answer (score 0):

With the help of css and java-script you can easily do it.
Here is an example
 [How do I put a clear button inside my HTML text input box like the iPhone does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803532/how-do-i-put-a-clear-button-inside-my-html-text-input-box-like-the-iphone-does)

Comment: but all example is to html input control and no to read only textbox

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all that work to make it read-only and avoid validation, why not combine a FilteredTextBoxExtender with the CalendarExtender.  Use the filter to block all non-numeric characters.  I still think it's better to do the validation.  It's as simple as DateTime.TryParse(), or you could do it client-side with the built-in FieldValidators.